# White screen on prestashop localhost migration to hosting with plesk

Tags: prestashop, plesk

I did a migration of my prestashop, to my hosting but when I go into my domain I see a white screen and I can't do nothing

I've changed ps_domain and ps_domain_ssl on the database and the ps_shop_url and I've checked the conection with the database and is all ok

all the files and directories have all the permisions

Comment: If I enable the debug mode on config/defines.inc I have a redirection error

Comment: A white screen could also be an error 500. Check your error_log file for details.

Comment: I hope you already solved it because it was 2 weeks ago but I think the problem is in ssl. database, table ps_configuration search for PS_SSL_ENABLED and  PS_SSL_ENABLED_EVERYWHERE and set from 0 to 1

Comment: yes, i'd changed PS_SSL_ENABLED and PS_SSL_ENABLED_EVERYWHERE and all works fine